# Using linearity of projection maps for proving differentiation is a coordinate-wise operation.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

I am trying to show that:

> If $f:U\subset \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ and  $a\in U$,then $f=(f_1,f_2,...,f_m)$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if $f_i$ is differentiable  at $a$ ,for all $1\leq i\leq m$ and $Df(a)=(Df_1(a),Df_2(a),...,Df_m(a))$.

I did this as follows:

Let $f$ be differentiable at $a$.

Then $f(x)=f(a)+\varphi(x-a)+\epsilon(x)\|x-a\|$ where $\epsilon(x)\to 0$ as $x\to a$ and $\varphi=Df(a)$.Apply the projection map $p_i:\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R$ on both sides and noting that $p_i$ is linear we get, $f_i(x)=f_i(a)+(p_i\circ \varphi)(x-a)+(p_i\circ \epsilon(x))\|x-a\|$ where $\epsilon_i(x)=p_i( \epsilon (x))\to p_i(0)=0$ as $x\to a$ because $p_i$ is a continuous linear map.So,$f_i$ are differentiable at $a$ and $Df_i(a)=p_i\circ Df(a)$ i.e. $Df(a)=(Df_1(a),Df_2(a),...,Df_m(a))$.

Conversely let, $f_i$ be differentiable at $a$ for all $i=1,2,...,m$.Then $f_i(x)=f_i(a)+\varphi_i(x-a)+\epsilon_i(x)\|x-a\|$ where $\epsilon_i(x)\to 0$ as $x\to a$ and $\varphi_i=Df_i(a)$ .Note that this is an equation in $\mathbb R$.Now $f(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x),...,f_m(x))=(f_1(a)+\varphi_1(x-a)+\epsilon_1(x)\|x-a\|,...,f_m(a)+\varphi_m(x-a)+\epsilon_m(x)\|x-a\|)=(f_1(a),...,f_m(a))+(\varphi_1(x-a),...,\varphi_m(x-a))+\|x-a\|(\epsilon_1(x),...,\epsilon_m(x))=f(a)+\varphi(x-a)+\|x-a\|\epsilon(x)$ where $\varphi=(\varphi_1,...,\varphi_m)$ and $\mathbb R^m\ni \epsilon(x)=(\epsilon_1(x),...,\epsilon_m(x))\to 0$ as $x\to a$ because $\|\epsilon (x)\|=\sqrt{\epsilon_1^2(x)+...+\epsilon_m^2(x)}\to 0$ as $x\to a$.So, $ Df(a)=\varphi=(Df_1(a),...,Df_m(a))$.

Is this method correct?

Comment: This is pretty much a dupe of [Derivative Normed Vector Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3249079/568204), where an analogous result is shown in the more general normed vector space setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn’t read in detail, but sure it seems correct. But if you know the chain rule, this is much more trivial (the explanations below are only “long” because I’m trying to explain some of the details).

- For $\implies$, you know $p_i$ is linear (between finite-dimensional spaces, hence continuous) so differentiable (everywhere, in particular at $f(a)$). Hence, by chain rule, $f_i=p_i\circ f$ is differentiable at $a$ (and $D(f_i)_a=D(p_i\circ f)_a=D(p_i)_{f(a)}\circ Df_a=p_i\circ Df_a$).
- Conversely, define the injections $\iota_i:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^m$, $x\mapsto (0,\dots, x,\dots, 0)$, with $x$ in the $i^{th}$ spot. These are linear (between finite-dimensional spaces, hence continuous) hence differentiable (everywhere). Now, note that $f=\sum_{i=1}^m\iota_i\circ f_i$. This is a sum of composites of differentiable functions, and hence $f$ is differentiable at $a$ (with $Df_a=\sum_{i=1}^m\iota_i\circ D(f_i)_a$, where I used linearity of derivatives, and that $\iota_i$ is a linear map so it is its own Frechet derivative at every point… just as I did above with $p_i$).